# Anchor: create PDA with seed that can change after already finding the program address

Tags: anchor, solana-program, pda

I want to create an PDA with a seed that could change after i already found the program address on the client side.

```
pub struct CreatePost<'info> {

    #[account(mut)]
    pub creator: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = creator,
        space = 8 + Post::MAX_SIZE, seeds = [b"post", category.name.as_bytes(), &category.post_count.to_be_bytes()], bump
    )]
    pub post: Account<'info, Post>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"category", category.name.as_bytes()], bump = category.bump
    )]
    pub category: Account<'info, Category>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"global"], bump = global.bump
    )]
    pub global: Account<'info, GlobalStats>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}
```

The initialzation of the post Account has the dependency to **category.post_count**, that could change, after someone else posted.

I'm calculating the PDA on the client like so:

```
const [postPDA, pdaBump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [
          anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("post"),
          anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("global"),
          Uint8Array.of(...count.toArray('be', 8))
        ],
        programId)
```

The problem is, that the PDA could have already been created by someone else, after i try to initialize it, resulting in not creating a new PDA.

However i always want to create a new PDA when i call create_post, that will increment after someone else posted.

Do i need to create the PDA manually or is it possible to calculate the seed in Anchor?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a `post_count` field for each owner (creator). This way, `creator` could be one of your seed sources, along with their post count, creating a unique address for each `creator` with every post.